# Retrieve ActiveMQ Header during mediation in WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2-esb

My ActiveMQ client is setting few custom header while posting message to ActiveMQ Queue, as shown below

```html
          MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
          TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("<Message>Test</Message>");
          
          message.setStringProperty("ID", "XYZ");
          message.setStringProperty("CODE", "COUNTRY_CODE");
          
          producer.send(message);
```

In WSO2 ESB sequence, I am trying to retrieve "ID" and "CODE" as

```html
   <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:ns3="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="ID" expression="get-property('axis2', 'ID')" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
   <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:ns3="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="CODE" expression="get-property('axis2', 'CODE')" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

But this is returning null, I even tried to set the scope as transport. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the following expression because the custom jms headers are stored in the transport layer.

```
 <property name="CREATE_PROXY - Config Params"
                  expression="get-property('transport','TRANSPORT_ID')"/>
```